# Why return types were different in ArrayList add methods?

Tags: java, oracle, arraylist

Why return types were different in [ArrayList.add(E e)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) and [ArrayList.add(int index, E element)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29) ? 
Can someone explain me kindfully ? Because of today I got a error as below ..

```
public void Foo(List<String> list) {
    // do something
}
..........
```

And call this method from my test class as `Foo(new ArrayList<String>().add("John"));`
I got a compilation error in my IDE . So , I noticed that [ArrayList.add(E e)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) method was not  `void` return type . If so , I have no idea why this method return **boolean** type.

> *PS: I thought [ArrayList.add(E e)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28E%29) method has void method for so long time before.*

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your link has the answer. Pay more attention!

`Returns true (as specified by Collection.add(E))`

From Collection.add(E):

`Returns true if this collection changed as a result of the call`

Also (thanks Mark Rotteveel):

"If a collection refuses to add a particular element for any reason other than that it already contains the element, it must throw an exception (rather than returning false). This preserves the invariant that a collection always contains the specified element after this call returns."

So if it returns `true`, the element was added, if it returns `false` the element was already there (such as in a `Set`) and in other cases an exception needs to be thrown (for example if a `Collection` would limit its size and not block).

And the reason for the differences is that the contract for `add(E)` is defined in `Collection`, whereas `add(int index, E e)` is defined in the `List` interface (and doesn't need to return anything). It could return `true` as well, but it would be useless. The other method **has** to return true, because otherwise it would break the contract for `Collection`.

Comment: You might also want to include the quote: _"If a collection refuses to add a particular element for any reason other than that it already contains the element, it must throw an exception (rather than returning false). This preserves the invariant that a collection always contains the specified element after this call returns."_ from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. He's asking why one overload returns `void` and the other `boolean`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel One method is defined in `Collection`, the other is defined in `List`.

Comment: `List` specifies that `add(E)` _must_ return `true` or throw, so there's no point in having a return value for `add(int, E)`.

Answer (score 4):

Collections.add(element) can be implemented by a Collection which does not add the element.  e.g

```
Collection<String> col1 = new HashSet<String>();
col1.add("hi"); // return true
col1.add("hi"); // return false
```

As ArrayList also inherits add(element) from Collection, it must follow the same interface.

The List.add(int, element) is not inherited from Collection as only List is indexable. It wouldn't make sense for it to be a Collection method.  This means it can only be implemented by collections which always add the element (or throw an Exception) So the return of `true` every time would be redundant.